# TFS gives error when releasing: Neither the Azure module nor the AzureRM module was found

Tags: azure, tfs, continuous-deployment

[The screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNX4.png)

Can you please help me to understand why I am getting this error and what I should do to fix it? I have searched the stackoverflow and googled it, however no success. I am using "Deploy AzureRM Web App" in TFS. AzureRM service endpoint is working successfully. The connection has been verified.

Let me know please if you require more info. Appreciate your help!

Comment: you are probably using wrong agent, check that you are using windows hosted agent or if you are using your own agent install the module on that agent

Comment: Thank you! I have checked the modules on the agent machine and AzureRM was missing. This question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was in the missing AzureRM module on the agent.